# How to check and convert Python function string arguments to list type inside the function?

Tags: python, function, type-conversion, arguments, iteration

I have a function with several arguments and I want some of them to check are they list type. Those that are not should be converted to list type.

I decided to do it by making the list of arguments to iterate inside function.

In general it's not an issue if I just iterating through list of similar variables out of function. But if I put it in function as the list of arguments it fails.

That works if you just want put string variable into list

```
parameter_1 = 'a'
if type(parameter_1) is not list:
    parameter_1 = list(parameter_1.split())
print(parameter_1, type(parameter_1))
```

[Out] `['a'] <class 'list'>`

That works if you iterating list of variables checking it's type. Have to use locals()

```
parameter_1 = 'a'
parameter_2 = ['b','c']
process_list = ['parameter_1', 'parameter_2']
for i in process_list:
    if type(locals()[i]) is not list:
        locals()[i] = list(locals()[i].split())
print(parameter_1, type(parameter_1))
```

[Out] `['a'] <class 'list'>`

But if you put it into function:

```
def my_function(
    parameter_1='d',
    parameter_2=['e','f']
):
    process_list = ['parameter_1', 'parameter_2']
    for i in process_list:
        if type(locals()[i]) is not list:
            print('recognised:', i, locals()[i], type(locals()[i]))
            locals()[i] = list(locals()[i].split())
            print('after conversion:', locals()[i], type(locals()[i]))
    print(parameter_1, type(parameter_1))
my_function()
```

[Out]

```
recognised: parameter_1 d <class 'str'>
after conversion: d <class 'str'>
d <class 'str'>
```

Nothing changes but I expected

```
recognised: parameter_1 d <class 'str'>
after conversion: ['d'] <class 'list'>
['d'] <class 'list'>
```

I'm novice to Python and programming at all and suppose it is something connected with locals/globals but can't figure it out for a couple days.

Comment: You're going down a road of writing very complex code for little gain. Don't muck around with variable variables and modifying locals. Just don't. Not only does it not work, it makes the code extremely hard to comprehend. You can produce a helper function which takes a value, transforms it into a list if needed, and returns it. You can then apply it to your parameters like `parameter_1 = transform(parameter_1)`. This is perfectly sufficient, and less code and more readable than your current approach.

Comment: If you do have so many parameters that you think it becomes easier to do it with variable variables, your first step should be to stop and think if this is really a function design that makes sense. If you still think it makes sense, then work with `*args` and `**kwargs` to accept parameters as an iterable/dict, which you can easily iterate over and which you can manipulate, e.g. `args = map(transform, args)`.

Comment: To put it in a single sentence: think about data structures like lists and dicts, instead of meta-modifying the variables of your program.

Comment: Okay. I guess I got the point. Thanks.

Comment: @deceze But this seems interesting. Why are `locals()` and `globals()` even modifiable? And why is `locals()` not modifiable within functions? I can set variable names not allowed by Python syntax this way, but can't use it.